# ValidateLogin Internal Error 500

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, netbeans, internal-server-error

I'm attempting to create a login process using JSPs and linking them to my MySQL database. The issue I have encountered is an internal error (500) in my browser after I click "login".

I have setup my web.xml for the servlet ValidateLogin.java and I know that is not the issue. Can someone please help me here? I'll place down my code below that involves my HtmlServlet Request and Response.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ValidateLogin extends HttpServlet {

    Connection connect;
    ResultSet result;
    String username, password, query;
    DatabaseConnection database_connection;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {

    // Code Here...

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I worked out the issue...

Change code from to...

```
    //FROM
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UF-8");
    //TO
    response.setContentType("text/html");
```